# How to loop over an object in an array of JSON data and check if their name contains a certain string?

Tags: reactjs

Im building a recipe app that takes external api data and displays it on the page. I wanted to know if there was a way to check all the key names in the object for a certain string "strIngredient..." and display all the values that contain the key name "strIngredient..."

this is my drinks.js component

```
import React from "react";

function Drinks({ drinkList }) {
  if (!drinkList) return <></>;
  return (
    <section className="drinkCard">
      <h1 className="drinks-name">{drinkList.drinks[0].strDrink}</h1>
      <img src={drinkList.drinks[0].strDrinkThumb} alt="Drink" />
      <p>
        <strong>Category: </strong>
        {drinkList.drinks[0].strCategory}
      </p>
      <p>
        <strong>Alcoholic: </strong>
        {drinkList.drinks[0].strAlcoholic}
      </p>
      <p>
        <strong>Instructions: </strong>
        {drinkList.drinks[0].strInstructions}
      </p>
      <ol>{showIngredientsList()}</ol>
    </section>
  );
}

export default Drinks;
```

and here is a picture of the JSON data (I want to only retrieve the values of the ones with key name containing "strIngredient") :
[image]

Comment: you can do something like this `drinkList?.drink[0]['strIngredient1']` to get the `value` of that `key`.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by mapping the array and using `Object.entries` on each object to be able to filter the resulting array of `[key, value]` by their keys, then merge it back to an object.

```js
var drinks = [{
    idDrink: "11000",
    strDrink: "Mojito",
    strDrinkAlternative: null,
    strTags: "IBA,ContenporaryClassic,Alcohol",
    strVideo: null,
    strInstructions: "Muddle mint leaves with sugar and...",
    strInstructionsES: "Muddle mint leaves with sugar and...",
    strInstructionsDE: "Muddle mint leaves with sugar and...",
    strIngredient1: "Light rum",
    strIngredient2: "Lime",
    strIngredient3: "Sugar",
    strIngredient4: "Mint",
    strIngredient5: "Soda Water",
    strIngredient6: null,
    strIngredient7: null,
    strIngredient8: null,
}];

var filteredDrinks = drinks.map((drink) =>
    Object.fromEntries(
        Object.entries(drink).filter(([key, _value]) =>
            key.includes('strIngredient')
        )
    )
);

// to get only the values of `strIngredients*`:

var filteredDrinksValues = drinks.map((drink) =>
    Object.entries(drink)
        .filter(([key, _value]) => key.includes('strIngredient'))
        .map(([_key, value]) => value)
);
```

Comment: it says that drinks is undefined which is my main problem in getting data that was fetched in another file (Home.js). How do I make it work in this component?

Comment: The original data fetching is not related to the question, please update your question and code example, or even better, make a codesandbox with your code

Answer (score 0):

About the logics, you can do something like this then

```js
for (const property in drinkList?.drink[0]) {
  // property would be the key
  // drinkList?.drink[0][property] would be the value
  
  // console log value that have key 'strIngredient'
  property.include('strIngredient') && console.log(drinkList?.drink[0][property])
}
```